# How do I sort my sqldatasource records in a particular way

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, sqldatasource

I have my SqlDataSource control. It basically has UpdateCommand and SelectCommand. My gridview is bound to this sqldatasource control. My SelectCommand is:

```
Select Username, Status from Users Order by LastLoginTime desc
```

I have my table something like this:

```
ABC IN PROGESS  somedate
DEF COMPLETE    somedate
PQR PENDING     somedate
JLM COMPLETE    somedate
LKM IN PROGESS  somedate
```

Currently query results are sorted by lastlogintime (i.e somedate). But I want my results to be sorted by 2nd column(say this column name is Status). I want the records to be sorted in such a way that 1st all users whole status is IN PROGRESS should appear then PENDING and then COMPLETE. As you can say this is not a simple order by clause.

How can I sort in this way with my SqlDataSource control?

Comment: Since its an string column (as per the data shown), i guess you need to override compare method on this column and write your logic to sort.

Comment: @zenwalker: I know this is the standard approach. However this code is super ugly. There are no classes where to override this method. All sql is directly mixed up in the aspx page. This code is gifted to us by some company.

Comment: As Martin Fowler says, you first have to refactor major part of th code which is in speghetti shape. Then you can put this logic in a class where you can override Compare method which is an Object class virtual method.

Comment: @zenwalker: That is a time consuming and better approach. I have to complete this within 2 hours so it's next to impossible for me. I have an idea. I will use UNION magic and hard code those three values of 'COMPLETE','IN PROGRESS' etc ;).A patch that works..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [Custom Sort Order](http://www.emadibrahim.com/2007/05/25/custom-sort-order-in-a-sql-statement/) using `CASE` in SQL. Try this

```
SELECT Name, Status FROM UsersOrder ORDER BY CASE Status
    WHEN 'IN PROGESS' THEN 1
    WHEN 'PENDING' THEN 2
    WHEN 'COMPLETE' THEN 3
    ELSE 99
END
```

So in effect your SelectCommand will be a hideous one-liner. :)

```
SelectCommand="SELECT Name, Status FROM UsersOrder ORDER BY CASE Status WHEN 'IN PROGESS' THEN 1 WHEN 'PENDING' THEN 2 WHEN 'COMPLETE' THEN 3 ELSE 99 END"
```

I am afraid this is the only solution.

Comment: mann gaye boss..the most easiest solution and better than my union approach. I wish I could give you few more votes.

Comment: happy to help... i guess you have some time left on your two hour task. enjoy :)